# How to make a common spring boot project has dependencies for other 3 separate spring boot projects?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

If I have 3 independent separate spring boot projects and they all have many common dependencies which leads to large size of each war.

Is there a method to make another separate project that has all these common dependencies and the projects points to this project without making it a jar as this will still make the size large of each war?

Comment: Can't be done.  You can create a parent project, the same way that spring-boot-starter-parent works, but it'll still have to bring in all the necessary dependencies.  There is no free lunch here.

Comment: But the 3 projects will still be under this parent and can't be deployed separately correct?

Comment: The 3 projects are independent and don't want to put them under one parent project that requires to deploy every time the three modules

Comment: No free lunch.  I can't help you.  Disk storage is cheap and plentiful.  The size of your WAR file shouldn't be a concern.  You're obsessed with the wrong problem.

Comment: Sure you can. If you run all applications on the same Tomcat instance, you can add those libraries to Tomcat itself, and they can be made available to the applications. Other application servers might have similar features.

Comment: @Jorn You could indeed add them to the server path introducing a whole new slew of issues with classloaders, class loading, singletons etc. etc. I'm glad we moved away from that era.

Comment: @M.Deinum I didn't say it was a good idea. But it's an answer to the question, and proves that the "no" everyone else is giving just isn't true.

Comment: @Jorn what about the build of the project itself? if I remove these dependencies from the project it will have errors and will give errors while trying to generate the war

Comment: Correct, you will need those deps while developing. There's no changing that.

Answer (score 0):

The only dirty trick that I can guess is:

1. Encapsulate the common logic into libraries.
2. Put them on a shared server folder.
3. Add that folder to each application classpath (reference them in maven by the `system` scope).

Comment: you mean the project with the common dependencies make it a JAR and make the projects read it from a path in the server? but what about building the project? it will find the jars missing

Comment: No, you have to put only the common dependencies in a shared folder, then reference them in your classpath.

Comment: Do you mean "provided" scope? I make a maven project with the common dependencies and extract it as a library and deploy it on weblogic server. And when I make the scope "provided" in one of the dependency in my project, that is in the created library, it is still not seen by my project, what I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Spring Boot Thin Launcher](https://github.com/spring-projects-experimental/spring-boot-thin-launcher). With it you can create a jar that will only contain your application classes. When started, the first time it will download the needed dependencies into a directory and add them to the classpath.

Now when you have multiple applications which run on the same server they could re-use the same repository for the jars, which would download them only once.

**NOTE:** This is an experimental feature so YMMV.

**NOTE2:** Generally the size of the archive shouldn't matter, as disk-space is cheap nowadays. Focussing on other parts for optimizing developer experience will have a better ROI then this (probably).

Comment: I read about it but when I try to deploy the jar (not war as usual which includes all dependencies) on weblogic server it gives error as I think it doesn't have the WEB-INF folder, so is there something missing?

Comment: You cannot use this with a war only an executable jar. If you are on weblogic (first I'm sorry for you) there isn't much you can do.

Comment: so the thin jar can't be deployed on weblogic server correct?

Comment: Correct. As you cannot deploy a jar file.

Comment: Is a jar file (which is a thin jar in my case) can be deployed on other servers not weblogic?

Comment: No. Only war and ear. Also why use weblogic instead of just running the jar?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255275/discussion-between-programmer-and-m-deinum).